Resizing an equation with resizebox issues an error in beamer
I want to resize an equation in order to have it fit into my block so I have the following
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{commandes}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{theorem}
        For each $X\in\obj$ there exists a first quadrant spectral sequence
            $$E_{p,q}^2=L_pF(L_qG(X))\Rightarrow L_{p+q}FG(X).$$
        The exact sequence of low degree terms is 
            $$\resizebox{\displaywidth}{!}{L_2FG(X)\to L_2F(G(X)) \to F(L_1G(X)) \to L_1FG(X) \to L_1F(G(X)) \to 0}.$$
    \end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

which provides the error

Missing $ inserted.

but also the warning

Overfull \hbox (3.0524pt too wide) detected at line 411

at the \end{frame} line but still provides
.
However this doesn't produce any error in another document (I copy-pasted it from the other document) as well as if I get rid of the \resizebox as such:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{commandes}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{theorem}
        For each $X\in\obj$ there exists a first quadrant spectral sequence
            $$E_{p,q}^2=L_pF(L_qG(X))\Rightarrow L_{p+q}FG(X).$$
        The exact sequence of low degree terms is 
            $$L_2FG(X)\to L_2F(G(X)) \to F(L_1G(X)) \to L_1FG(X) \to L_1F(G(X)) \to 0.$$
    \end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

which provides

Ultimately, since both inputs provide the expected output it doesn't really matter (a priori) in the end but I would like to understand what is causing this error and what I can do to get rid of it

Never resize elements which contain text. Choose a suitable font size instead (or split the equation over two lines)

And don't use $$...$$ in latex, see Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$?

The argument of \resizebox is in text, so you can't se math mode commands there. You need to switch again into math mode.

You shouldn't scale elements which contain text. If you really must squeeze the equation into a single line and can't split it into multiple lines, then better choose a suitable font size instead of scaling:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{theorem}
        The exact sequence of low degree terms is 
        {\small\[L_2FG(X)\to L_2F(G(X)) \to F(L_1G(X)) \to L_1FG(X) \to L_1F(G(X)) \to 0.\]}
    \end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



This would disrupt line spacing before the display if it has more than one line.

@egreg Yes it will. Personally I would prefer to split the equation over two lines.

Another solution: Find a suitable abbreviation for an often-used term. E.g., replace all instances of G(X) in the second displayed equation with, say, \mathcal{G}.

\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

%\usepackage{commandes} % ?

\usepackage[scr=rsfs]{mathalfa}
\DeclareMathOperator{\obj}{obj}
\providecommand{\GG}{\mathcal{G}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\begin{theorem}
For each $X\in\obj(\mathscr{C})$ there exists a first quadrant spectral sequence
\[
E_{p,q}^2=L_pF(L_qG(X))\Rightarrow L_{p+q}FG(X).
\]
Put $\GG\equiv G(X)$. The exact sequence of low degree terms is 
\[
L_2F\GG\to L_2F(\GG) \to F(L_1\GG) \to L_1F\GG \to L_1F(\GG) \to 0.
\]
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


I'd choose to split the long sequence across two lines, rather than scaling.
Anyway, I also show a method for reducing the size that avoids the (wrong) construction “{\small[}]”, see comparison at the end.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{With split sequence}

\begin{theorem}
  The exact sequence of low degree terms is 
  \begin{multline*}
    L_2FG(X)\to L_2F(G(X)) \to F(L_1G(X)) \\
    \to L_1FG(X) \to L_1F(G(X)) \to 0.
  \end{multline*}
\end{theorem}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{With size reduction}

\begin{theorem}
  The exact sequence of low degree terms is 
  \[
  \medmath{L_2FG(X)\to L_2F(G(X)) \to F(L_1G(X)) \to L_1FG(X) \to L_1F(G(X)) \to 0.}
  \]
\end{theorem}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


Why is \small a bad method? Compare the two instances below: you clearly see that the spacing in the text above the display is wrong.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{With good size reduction}

\begin{theorem}
  Nonsense text added at the beginning in order to have more than one line.
  Nonsense text added at the beginning in order to have more than one line.
  The exact sequence of low degree terms is 
  \[
  \medmath{L_2FG(X)\to L_2F(G(X)) \to F(L_1G(X)) \to L_1FG(X) \to L_1F(G(X)) \to 0.}
  \]
  Nonsense text added at the end in order to have more than one line.
  Nonsense text added at the end in order to have more than one line.
  Nonsense text added at the end in order to have more than one line.
\end{theorem}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{With bad size reduction}

\begin{theorem}
  Nonsense text added at the beginning in order to have more than one line.
  Nonsense text added at the beginning in order to have more than one line.
  The exact sequence of low degree terms is 
  {\small\[
  L_2FG(X)\to L_2F(G(X)) \to F(L_1G(X)) \to L_1FG(X) \to L_1F(G(X)) \to 0.
  \]}%
  Nonsense text added at the end in order to have more than one line.
  Nonsense text added at the end in order to have more than one line.
  Nonsense text added at the end in order to have more than one line.
\end{theorem}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


